# How to use google page speed API in java class ? Please provide any sample example for the same

Tags: java, api, google-api, google-api-java-client

I need to write a java class to call/request the google pagespeed API, And create a test report from the json result.

If anyone have such implementation using the java, Please guide me to implement.

Comment: Someone at Google should really write a tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the google pagespeedapi using the link
 https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed 
along with the strategy,key and the url needed for testing.

Answer (score 0):

In the package description you can at least find some hints how to use the Java Classes:

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pagespeedonline/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/pagespeedonline/package-use.html

I agree there sould be a more detailed usage example. What I figured out so far maybe is a good starting point, I hope this will help some people.

```
    String url = "...";

    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new  com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory();
    HttpTransport transport = com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = null; //this can be null here!
    Pagespeedonline p = new Pagespeedonline.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer).build();

    Pagespeedonline.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed runpagespeed  = p.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(url);
    Result result = runpagespeed.execute();
    FormattedResults formattedresults = result.getFormattedResults();

    System.out.println(formattedresults.toPrettyString());
```